# How to put <script src="http://example.com/script.js"></script> in other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example:
Some service provided me with JavaScript code for rendering subscription form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/form.js"></script>
```

Everything works great!

But I need to get this code from other source (ajax for example) and put it on the page dynamically I just can't do it.

Something like that:

```
var result = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/form.js"></script>';
$('#element').html(result);
```

Nothing shows up.
Yeah I know I can create script element, then edit src attribute and then append element somewhere, but the problem is that result might be HTML or HTML/CSS or JavaScript (script element).

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you search the variable for script or the type of html element or css, then act on it depending on which one is true?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to gain access to the .js itself, you can get it with an AJAX request to read the file.

Here is an example using jQuery's `ajax` function. Non-jQuery AJAX requests are easily done, you'll just need to do a quick Google search for the syntax.

```
$.ajax('http://example.com/form.js')
    .done(function(data) { $('#element).html(data); });
```

If you need to output, you can treat a JS file just like any other text file.

Upon rereading your request, you might be looking to run the JS then grab whatever output that generates and copy that. If that is indeed the case, then it depends on the script as it could do literally anything, so we'll need more information about what the script does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function loadFile(url) {
    function callback() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) { // 4 = Loaded
            if (req.status == 200) {
                if (req.responseText.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '').indexOf("<") == 0) {
                    eval(req.responseText); // It's a script, probably
                } else {
                    // It's HTML, probably
                    // Insert req.responseText in some element on your page
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = callback;
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send("");
}
</script>
```

Run the loadFile() function with the script source URL as argument.